# TikZ: draw only a certain central length of a given path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two nodes (A) and (B), and I want to only draw a central segment of the straight line between them, of a certain given length (say 2cm, but will vary). Is there some way I can do this? I am guaranteed that (A) and (B) are at least 2cm apart.

I know about shorten < and shorten >, but the problem is that I don't know the exact amount to shorten by, and I don't want to have to do the calculation myself each time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I didn't read the question very carefully and thought you want to draw the middle part of of *any* kind of path. So I created a (meta-)decoration to do just that. For straight lines the other solutions given here are of course a lot simpler.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

% A simple empty decoration, that is used to ignore the last bit of the path
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ignore}{final}
{
\state{final}{}
}

% Declare the actual decoration.
\pgfdeclaremetadecoration{middle}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[
        width={(\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength - \the\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)/2},
        next state=middle
    ]
    {\decoration{moveto}}

    \state{middle}[
        width={\the\pgfdecorationsegmentlength},
        next state=final
    ]
    {\decoration{curveto}}

    \state{final}
    {\decoration{ignore}}
}

% Create a key for easy access to the decoration (as suggested by Jake).
\tikzset{middle segment/.style={decoration={middle},decorate, segment length=#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=2pt]   
    \fill (0,0) circle;
    \fill (4,0) circle;
    \draw[middle segment=2cm,double,red,->] (0,0) to[out=30,in=150] (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Excellent! Adding to that: If you define a style `\tikzset{middle segment/.style={decoration={middle},decorate, segment length=#1}}`, you can easily draw line segments with different lengths using `\draw [middle segment=<length>] (a) -- (b);`

Comment: @Jake: Good idea!

Comment: Hi Caramdir. I like your solution, it seems really flexible! I tried modify it so that the line segment would have an arrow at the end, but without any luck. Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: @Jamie: Add `\afterdecoration
{
\pgfsetarrowsend{to}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
}` to the middle state (right after `...curveto}`, before the second `}`). You can replace `to` by the arrow type you want. See also the example on page 601 of the (v2.10) manual.

Comment: That's great! I actually just found that myself. But now I've also noticed that my [double] option is getting ignored, if I want make the line into two parallel lines ... how can I add that in?

Comment: @Jamie: I have no simple idea right now how to add the arrow and still have the path be drawn with all the options set with TikZ.

Comment: I imagine that to get the options set you're going to have to parse the option list again.  So use a key to gather the options that you want to apply, say `\tikzset{middle style/.style={green,->}}` then in the decoration `\let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty\let\tikz@mode=\pgfutil@empty\tikzset{middle style}\tikz@mode\tikz@options`.  Or something like that.

Comment: @Andrew: That almost works, but ignores `double`. So one would have to copy steps 6 and 8 from `\tikz@finish`, which is rather more hackish than I would like.

Comment: Turns out that there is a simple solution: Just ignore the last bit of the path :-). Unfortunately, `<-` still doesn't work as expected, but I'm out of ideas for that.

Comment: How could I shift the segment a bit up/down relative to the path. I am trying to use `raise=-4ex`. Where to put it?

Answer (score 16):

The `calc` library eats this sort of thing for breakfast.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {A};
\node (b) at (3,3) {B};
\draw ($($(a)!.5!(b)$)!1cm!(a)$) --  ($($(a)!.5!(b)$)!1cm!(b)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The syntax works as follows: `$...$` is interpreted as a "coordinate calculation" and it returns a coordinate.  We start with `$(a)!.5!(b)$` which is halfway between `(a)` and `(b)`.  Then we move `1cm` from this point towards `(a)`.  That's our starting point.  We draw a line from that to the same but with `(b)` in place of `(a)`.

Result:

[image: centre path]

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I don't really know much about the calc package, this is a good advertisement for it.

Answer (score 7):

Along the same line as the other answers, but also using the intersections library.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\length}{2}

\coordinate (A) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (B) at (4,4);

\coordinate (mid) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);

\path[name path=line,draw=lightgray] (A) node[left] {$A$} -- (B)  node[right] {$B$};
\path[name path=circle,draw=lightgray] (mid) circle[radius=0.5*\length];

\draw [red, blue,ultra thick, name intersections={of=line and circle}]
(intersection-1) -- (intersection-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: line]

The length of the blue segment is determined by the value of the macro `\length`.

Another option is to clip the path :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\length}{2}

\coordinate[label=left:$A$] (A) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate[label=right:$B$] (B) at (4,4);

\coordinate (mid) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);

\begin{scope}
\clip (mid) circle[radius=0.5*\length];
\draw[blue,ultra thick] (A) -- (B);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This is a great illustration of named paths.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jamie : I just realized that the length of the line segment is the diameter of the circle !! I must divide the radius of the circle by 2. I fixed the code, but not the picture.

Comment: Thanks Frédéric. It's funny that the first three solutions manage to do it in four different ways!

Answer (score 6):

How about that?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % def Points
    \fill (0,0) coordinate (A) circle (1pt) (5,2) coordinate (B) circle (1pt); 
    % two nodes A and B
    \node [below] at (A) {Node A};
    \node [above] at (B) {Node B};
    % line between
    \draw ($(A)!1cm!(B)$) -- ($(A)!3cm!(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

First I define two corrdinates, draw them and add two nodes.
The I the `⟨p⟩!⟨factor/dimension⟩!⟨q⟩` syntax to get specified points between A and B.
Unfortunately in my solution you have to use two dimes to get a defined length. In ths case 3cm - 1cm = 2cm segment length.

See PGF manual, section “4.2.1 Using Partway Calculations for the Construction of D” in the Euclid Tutorial