# Combine shorten and bend option in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows

Is there a way to combine the `bend left` and `shorten` option to make an arc shorter **while keeping its shape** otherwise?

i.e., when I do

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[] (n1) at (0,0) {1};
\node[] (n2) at (4,0) {2};
\draw[->] (n1) to [bend left, shorten >=1cm] (n2);
\draw[->] (n1) to [bend left] (n2); % original arc
\end{tikzpicture}
```

the shortened arrow has a different shape than the original one.

Comment: Sry, you are right. I fixed the example...

Comment: I'm not very sure I understood your problem correctly. It it that when shortened, your arcs will be less like circular arcs, but you would like to preserve it?

Comment: Exactly. They should have the same form as unshortened, just end earlier.

Comment: Your example does not work.  The `shorten >` option cannot be applied to a subpath, only to the whole path, so in your example, it gets ignored.  What you probably want to do is `\draw[->, shorten >=1cm] (n1) to [bend left] (n2);`.

Comment: You should take a look at the following question, with the accepted answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18617/tikz-draw-only-a-certain-central-length-of-a-given-path/18622#18622

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be very precise, the curvature added to the line with `bend` doesn't exactly make it an arc. Or rather it *looks* like an arc, but mathematically speaking it is not one (it is a Bézier curve if I'm not mistaken). Hence, when shortened the way you did in the example, it will be a bit, well... different. I think `shorten` was implemented with really short distances in mind, little adjustments, where the difference between the original curve and the correction is (almost) imperceptible.

Beside the solution by @Jan Hlavacek, you could try the following two.

One thing is to explicitly draw a Bézier (with `controls`) and play around with the control points, but that can be a lot of guesswork. Instead you could try playing either with the `<angle>` option `bend` takes (see code below) - not perfect, but satisfactory, I believe - or draw a curve between the endpoints (`n1` and `n2` in your case) and make visible only part of it (see also below):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[] (n1) at (0,0) {1};
\node[] (n2) at (4,0) {2};
\draw[->] (n1) to [bend left] (n2); % original arc

% solution 1

\draw[->, blue, shorten >=1cm] (n1) to [bend left=27] (n2);

% solution 2

\pgfpathcurvebetweentime{0.05}{0.75}{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{1}{0.9}}{\pgfpointxy{3}{0.9}}{\pgfpointxy{4}{0}}
\pgfsetarrowsend{to}
\pgfsetstrokecolor{red}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The `\pgfpathcurvebetweentime` takes the parameters: visible part beginning at portion `<start>` of curve, visible part ending at portion `<end>` of curve, start of actual curve, control point 1, control point 2, end of actual curve. As you can see, this is also a Bézier curve, but since all arcs can be modeled as Béziers, the resulting curve will also look good. In any cas, you must probably fiddle a bit with the controls coordinates, but this could be calculated and also, the coordinates of the nodes could be extracted to make the result more generic.

Comment: Your second solution is the Right One.  You can take the control points from the original curve and use them as the input to the `\pgfpathcurvebetweentime` call.  Then you will get the right path, just shortened a little.  So that does do exactly what the questioner wants.  Of course, it should be nicely wrapped in a little package!

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to load the `bending` library - now shortened arrows will follow the original path. To shorten a non-arrow following original path, you need to turn it into an arrow using the no arrow head `-_` like this:

```
\documentclass[margin=1 cm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[] (n1) at (0,0) {1};
\node[] (n2) at (4,0) {2};
\draw[->] (n1) to [bend left] (n2); % original arc
\draw[->, red, shorten >=1cm] (n1) to [bend left] (n2); %shortened following original path
\draw[-_, green, shorten >=2cm] (n1) to [bend left] (n2); %shortened following original path without arrow
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Shortened arrow following original path]

Answer (score 2):

You need to play with the `in` and `out` angles.  This seems to work for your specific example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[] (n1) at (0,0) {1};
   \node[] (n2) at (4,0) {2};
   \draw[very thick, red, ->, shorten >=1cm]  (n1) to[out=30,in=156,relative] (n2);
   \draw[->] (n1) to [bend left] (n2); % original arc
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you actually magnify the picture a lot, it does not completely match the original path, but it is pretty close.  There is probably a way to calculate the `in` angle, but I am not sure how, I just got there numbers by guessing and experimenting.