# Attach arrow head to curveto decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, decorations

In relation to this question: [Shorten curved arrow proportionally to length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568648/shorten-curved-arrow-proportionally-to-length/577402#577402)

I  have tried to use a `curveto` decoration to make a proportional shortening of a curve. My only problem is the arrow head. Is it possible to attach the arrow head to the decoration and not to the path?

---

"Shortened" with `pre=moveto`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta, bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\mypath}{(0,0) to[out=80, in=100, min distance=1cm] (1,0)}
\draw[ultra thick] \mypath;
\draw[red, ->, decoration={curveto, pre=moveto, pre length=0.5*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}, decorate] \mypath; %relative shortening
%\draw[pink, {_[sep=1cm]}->] \mypath; %absolute shortening
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Curve with arrow head turned]

---

"Shortened" with `post=moveto`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta, bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\mypath}{(0,0) to[out=80, in=100, min distance=1cm] (1,0)}
\draw[ultra thick] \mypath;
\draw[green, ->, decoration={curveto, post=moveto, post length=0.5*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}, decorate] \mypath; %relative shortening
%\draw[orange, -{>[sep=1cm]}] \mypath; %absolute shortening
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Curve with arrow head turned and detached]

---

I know that the arrow head can be made afterwards with `markings`, but my question is about making a "`curveto with arrow`" decoration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If shortened with `pre=moveto`, adding a short `post length=<length>` (accompanied with a `post=lineto|curveto` of course) works.

If shortened with `post=moveto`, changing it to `post=empty` where `empty` is a newly defined dummy decoration that does nothing (not even a moveto) seems to work.

Note this doesn't work for starting arrow(s). **Caution**: The rest sentences in current paragraph may be totally wrong. Decoration is just a (powerful and complicated) soft path substitution, and I see no chance to do a moveto action with out adding a moveto soft path. Maybe a one-time transformation matrix? Or patch the arrow internals to conditionally skip the first moveto?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, arrows.meta, bending}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{empty}{final}{
  \state{final}{}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\mypath}{(0,0) to[out=80, in=100, min distance=1cm] (1,0)}
  \draw[ultra thick] \mypath;
  \draw[red, ->, decoration={curveto, 
    pre=moveto, 
    pre length=0.5*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength, 
    post=curveto,   % <<< added
    post length=1pt % <<< added
  }, decorate] \mypath; %relative shortening
  %\draw[orange, -{>[sep=1cm]}] \mypath; %absolute shortening
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand{\mypath}{(0,0) to[out=80, in=100, min distance=1cm] (1,0)}
  \draw[ultra thick] \mypath;
  \draw[green, ->, decoration={curveto,
    post=empty,     % <<< changed
    post length=0.5*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength
  }, decorate] \mypath; %relative shortening
  %\draw[orange, -{>[sep=1cm]}] \mypath; %absolute shortening
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool - I learned a lot. What if the `curveto` decoration itself had a `pre` and `post` - I can not currently wrap my head around it. -something with `show path construction` and redefine `curveto` in terms of a decoration with `curveto` ... wait.. what. I need to sleep.

Comment: I am guessing `pre` and `post` is built upon `curveto`. `curveto` is an ordinary decoration [declared by `\pgfdeclaredecoration`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/d835e0312028e7e398626bdd77e5effeaab280f0/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex#L2111-L2144), while `pre` and `post` are part of a meta decoration `tikz@internal` [declared by `\pgfdeclaremetadecoration`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/d835e0312028e7e398626bdd77e5effeaab280f0/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex#L55-L71) and making use of `curveto` and the like.