# Line Offset with 'latex' Arrow and 'shorten' Option

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to draw a line going off a part of a circle. The two lines get an offset when I use `>=latex` arrow. The same holds for the `shorten` option. One of them is enough to create the offset.

It disapears when I remove `>=latex` and `shorten...` from style definition.

Is it possible to use `latex` arrows and `shorten` option without an offset?

EDIT:
I add a red circle to coordinate `mid1`. Why is `mid1` not on the path drawn from `coord1` to `coord2`?

After some research, I found these threads:
[Thread 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568648/shorten-curved-arrow-proportionally-to-length),
[Thread 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32442/combine-shorten-and-bend-option-in-tikz)

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[connA/.style = {thin, ->, >=latex, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt, bend left=45}]
    \coordinate (startcoord);
    \coordinate[below=3cm of startcoord] (coord1);
    \coordinate[left=3cm of startcoord] (coord2);
    
    \draw[connA] (coord1) to coordinate[midway] (mid1) (coord2);
    \draw[connA] (mid1) .. controls +(135:1cm) and +(0:1cm) .. (-4,-1);
    \fill[red] (mid1) circle (0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the MWE.]

I use TeX Live 2020.

Comment: I'm not sure about what `offset` means in this question but if you use or suppress `shorten` options, as starting and ending points are different the path will be different.

Comment: The second line doesn't start exactly on the first line. The path may be different but I use the relative coordinate `mid1` to start the second line.

Answer (score 3):

Shortening curves defined by bending a path always provides this kind of error, and it's a pain I struggled with too.
Recently, I made [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577402/204164) that is easily adaptable to your current issue, you already mentionned this thread.

It needs a bit of understanding but no big deal. You define your path using Bezier curve (with `.. controls`), then compute a series of point on this curve (from a starting point and for a certain length), then you draw a broken line between those points, using any decoration you want.[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (startcoord);
    \coordinate[below=3cm of startcoord] (coord1);
    \coordinate[left=3cm of startcoord] (coord2);

    % Defining the first path with Bezier curve    
    \def\route1{(coord1) .. controls +(-2,0) and +(0,-2).. (coord2)}

    % Definig the midpoint of this first path
    \path \route1 coordinate[midway] (mid1);
    
    % Defining starting point and length of the reduced arrow
    \def\start{0.01}
    \def\len{0.98}
    \def\numpoints{200} % number of points to draw a broken line following the curve

    %---------------------------------
    % First path from coord1 to coord2   
    %---------------------------------
    \path  \route1 
        {\foreach \i in {1,...,\numpoints} { coordinate[pos=\start+\len*\i/\numpoints] (p\i) } };
        
    % Drawing a broken line linking all 200 points, with the arrow decoration at the end
    \draw[-latex,thin] (p1)
        { \foreach \j in {2,...,\numpoints} {-- (p\j) } };
    
    %--------------------------
    % Second path from midpoint
    %--------------------------
                
    \def\route2{(mid1) .. controls +(135:1cm) and +(0:1cm) .. (-4,-1)}

    \def\start{0} \def\len{0.95} \def\numpoints{50}
    \path  \route2 
        {\foreach \i in {1,...,\numpoints} { coordinate[pos=\start+\len*\i/\numpoints] (p\i) } };
        
    \draw[-latex,thin] (p1)
        { \foreach \j in {2,...,\numpoints} {-- (p\j) } };
    
    % Decoration just in case
    \fill[red] (mid1) circle (0.5pt);    
    
    \fill[blue] (startcoord) circle (.5pt);
    \fill[blue] (coord1) circle (.5pt);
    \fill[blue] (coord2) circle (.5pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Currently, I tune the offset manually (see my answer). This is only a workaround and far away form being bullet proof. However, I have to think which solution suits better for my complete code.

Comment: Always have to get your hands into the dirt for these kinda thing. You did well, though.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I use a manual correction of this ugly offset:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[connA/.style = {thin, ->, >=latex, shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt, bend left=45}]
        \coordinate (startcoord);
        \coordinate[below=3cm of startcoord] (coord1);
        \coordinate[left=3cm of startcoord] (coord2);
        
        \draw[connA] (coord1) to coordinate[midway] (mid1) (coord2);
        % identify the correct angle for various positions of mid1 manually
        \draw[blue, thick] (mid1) to ([shift=(225:1mm)] mid1);
        \fill[red] (mid1) circle (0.5pt);
        % tune shift length manually
        \draw[connA] ([shift=(255:0.275mm)] mid1) .. controls +(135:1cm) and +(0:1cm) .. (-4,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]