# Adding vertical shift to a decoration (follow up on Q18617)

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, decorations

I am studying the answer of @Caramdir to [TikZ: draw only a certain central length of a given path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18617/tikz-draw-only-a-certain-central-length-of-a-given-path)

I would like the segment to be shifted orthogonally relative to the path.
I am trying to insert `raise` somewhere in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

% A simple empty decoration, that is used to ignore the last bit of the path                                                                  
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ignore}{final}
                     {
                       \state{final}{}
                     }

                     % Declare the actual decoration.                                                                                         
                     \pgfdeclaremetadecoration{middle}{initial}{
               \state{initial}[
                         width={(\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength - \the\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)/2},
                         next state=middle
                       ]
                             {\decoration{moveto}}

                     \state{middle}[
                               width={\the\pgfdecorationsegmentlength},
                               next state=final
                             ]
                                   {\decoration{curveto}}

                                   \state{final}
                                         {\decoration{ignore}}
                     }

% Create a key for easy access to the decoration (as suggested by Jake).                                                 
\tikzset{middle segment/.style={decoration={middle},decorate, segment length=#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=2pt]
     \fill (0,0) circle;
     \fill (4,2) circle;
     \draw[middle segment=2cm, double, red, ->] (0,0) to[bend right =20] (4,1);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the calc library to shift the path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,calc}

% A simple empty decoration, that is used to ignore the last bit of the path                                                                  
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ignore}{final}
                     {
                       \state{final}{}
                     }

                     % Declare the actual decoration.                                                                                         
                     \pgfdeclaremetadecoration{middle}{initial}{
               \state{initial}[
                         width={(\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength - \the\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)/2},
                         next state=middle
                       ]
                             {\decoration{moveto}}

                     \state{middle}[
                               width={\the\pgfdecorationsegmentlength},
                               next state=final
                             ]
                                   {\decoration{curveto}}

                                   \state{final}
                                         {\decoration{ignore}}
                     }

% Create a key for easy access to the decoration (as suggested by Jake).                                                 
\tikzset{middle segment/.style={decoration={middle},decorate, segment length=#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=2pt]
     \fill (0,0) circle;
     \fill (4,2) circle;
     \draw[middle segment=2cm, red, ->] (0,0) to[bend right =20] (4,1);
     \draw[middle segment=2cm, red, ->] ($(0,0)!1cm!90:(4,1)$) to[bend right =20] 
     ($(4,1)!1cm!-90:(0,0)$);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```